# Find the zeros of $h(z)=z^6-5z^4+3z^2-1$ within the unit disc - Verification

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $h(z)=z^6-5z^4+3z^2-1$.

Using Rouche's theorem, with $f(z)=-5z^4$ and $g(z)=z^6+3z^2-1$.

On the unit disc $\lvert f(z) \rvert =5 > \lvert 1+3-1 \rvert=\lvert g(z)\rvert $

And the number of zeros is 4 for $f(z)$ in the unit disc, so it is also five for $h(z)=f(z)+g(z)$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Found an old answer of mine, I chose $g(z)=z^6-1$ and $f(z)=-5z^4+3z^2$, and got the answer $4$ roots again.

Comment: You need to be more careful with $g$: its modulus is not constant, since it contains different powers. Moreover, $f$ has degree $4$, so it can't have $5$ zeros! (I think you mean $4$...)

Comment: @Chappers Thanks, corrected the 5 to a 4. I thought Rouche's theorem needs the modulus of $f$ to be greater on the boundary of the region, and there the powers are all powers of 1.

Comment: Simple example: if $|z|=1$, so $z=e^{i\theta}$, $|z+1| = \sqrt{(\cos{\theta}+1)^2+\sin^2{\theta}} = \sqrt{2+2\cos{\theta}} \neq |1+1|=2$.

Comment: @Chappers That's interesting, obviously I can't just plug in $z=1$ since there are all the $e^{i \theta}$ choices. But I have no idea how to treat the modulus otherwise. I found my old exam with that answer on it, I will post it as a note, but there I did the same process with different choices of functions. The professor accepted it, I haven't seen any Rouche's Theorem applications do anything more elaborate with the functions on the boundary than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first approach with $f(z) = -5z^4$ and $g(z) = z^6 + 3z^2 - 1$ doesn't work, because $g(i) = -1 - 3 - 1 = - 5$, hence $|f(i)| = |g(i)|$

So you don't have a strict inequality on the boundary of the region.  True that $|f(z)| >= |g(z)|$, but that's not enough for Rouche's theorem.

On the exam, your choice of functions does work for applying Rouche's theorem!  Taking $f(z) = -5z^4 + 3z^2$ and $g(z) = z^6 -1$, we now have that $|f(z)|$ takes its minimum of $2$ when and only when $z^2 = 1$, but at those points $|g(z)|$ is also at its minimum of $0$.  Meanwhile $|g(z)|$ takes its maximum at $2$, but this never happens when $z^2 = 1$.  We conclude that $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$ everywhere.

And $f(z)$ does have all four of its roots in the unit circle $(0, \pm\sqrt\frac{3}{5})$

Comment: Rouché's theorem doesn't apply if $f,g$ have a zero on the boundary of the region in question.

Comment: $f$ certainly can't (which is encoded in $f(z)| > |g(z)|$, but why can't $g$ have a zero on the boundary?

Comment: I was wrong, I mixed up $h$ & $g$.

Comment: $z^2$ is real also when $z=\pm i$ where $|f(z)|=8$ (which is not minimum of $f$), $f$'s minimum is at $\pm 1$

Comment: @Yea you're right, I don't know why I wrote that, it's wrong.  The reasoning still holds with '$z^2$ is real' replaced by '$z^2 = 1$'

Comment: @Badam Baplan How does one show that $f(z)=-5z^4+3z^2$ takes its minimum only at $z^2=1$? In other words, how does one show analytically that $|f(z)|>2$ on the contour $C_1(0)$ when $z\ne -1,1$?

Comment: @David T  If $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z$ is a complex variable with values on the circle $C_r(0)$, then $\mid z - u\mid$ is minimized when $Arg(z) = Arg(u)$.  This is  intuitively obvious from drawing a picture, and you can formalize it easily from the definition $\mid z \mid = z \bar{z}$.  In our case, we're trying to minimize $\mid 5z^2 - 3 \mid$ on $C_1(0)$, which happens at $z^2 = -1$.

Comment: @Badam Baplan Did you mean $u\in\mathbb C$ instead of $\lambda\in\mathbb C$? Do you mean $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$ instead of $|z|=z\overline{z}$? Then, I was able to draw a diagram and convince myself that $|z-u|$ is minimized when $\text{Arg}(z)=\text{Arg}(u)$. Now, how do I use $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$ to show that $|z-u|$ is minimized when $\text{Arg}(z)=\text{Arg(u)}$? Can you share some steps? Would you like me to ask this as a question on Math.StackExchange?

Comment: @David my bad, wrote that hastily from a phone. you caught the typos, it was intended as you guessed.  So, let's formalize the fact that $\mid z - u \mid$ is minimized when $\text{Arg}(z) = \text{Arg}(u)$... since rotation is an isometry, we can reduce to the case that $u$ is a positive real number.

Comment: @David (cont.) We're trying to show precisely that $\mid z - u \mid$ is minimized for $z \in C_r(0)$ when $z$ is a positive real.  But letting $z = x + iy$, with $x,y$ real variables, this is the same as minimizing $\sqrt{(x-u)^2 + y^2}$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  Now $(x - u)^2 + y^2 = x^2 - 2xu +u^2 + y^2 = r^2 + u^2 - 2xu$.  This last expression is linear, strictly monotonically decreasing in $x$.  Thus in case $u \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\mid z - u \mid$ is minimized when the $x$-coordinate of $z$ is maximized.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by Rouche's theorem if you choose $g$ correctly. For future reference, there exists a stronger form of Rouche's theorem, which can be easier to apply. Loosely speaking, most books say this:

> > **Rouche:** If $|f-g|<|g|$ on the boundary then $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeroes inside.

I don't know why they say that, because the following is no harder to prove:

> > **New and Improved Rouche:** If $|f-g|<|f|+|g|$ on the boundary then $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeroes inside.

See for example *Complex Made Simple*...